# Footer too high with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage, footer

my footer is too high. I'm creating a new template and now im using scrlayer-scrpage. In my last template, i used fancyhdr. Where is the mistake?
it is a difference about 2,5cm !!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}                %SI-Einheiten

%% Geometrieeigenschaften
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}


%% Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead[]{\headmark} 
\chead[]{} 
\ohead[]{Nico Wagner} 
\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[]{Seite \thepage} 
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
%\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but you still do not show an compilable code we can test your resulting pdf. Now you added two images but noone knows how they had been build? Please explain your issue better, describe what one can see on the added images. With my testfile I simply see an bottom margin of 3 cm you requested with `geometry` and centered inside the margin the footer line -- all that is as it should be!  So can you please mark in your screenshot with an red arrow where the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code I can not reproduce the issue.

Your example with `blindtext` and without the unrelated packages

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}% a4paper is default
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with older TeX Distributions
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%% Geometrieeigenschaften
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}

%% Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles% replace outdated syntax
\ihead{\headmark} 
\ohead{Nico Wagner} 
\ofoot{\pagemark} 
\renewcommand*\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\pagename~\thepage}}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}

\begin{document}
\addsec*{Kurzfassung}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

results in

[image: screenshot]

It seems that you are using package `setspace` with option `onehalfspacing`.

[image]

And there must be an explicit or implicit `\recalctypearea` which overwrites your `geometry` settings. Adding

```
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\recalctypearea% <- remove this
```

after your `\geometry` settings results in

[image: screenshot]

So you have to remove the explicit `\recalctypearea` or the code resulting in an `\recalctypearea` implicitly.